# Checking only for duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, group-by

I want to check if all the years in the category are the same and return if so,
so I want to return only 4 and 5. I could get this table, but no further.

```
SELECT 
    st.category,  
    EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM hiredate) as YEAR 
FROM NIKOVITS.EMP e, 
NIKOVITS.SAL_CAT st 
WHERE e.sal > st.lowest_sal AND e.sal < st.highest_sal
```

[image: Result of the query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select st.category, min(extract(year from e.hiredate)) yr
from nikovits.emp e
inner join nikovits.sal_cat st 
    on  e.sal > st.lowest_sal 
    and e.sal < st.highest_sal
group by st.category
having min(extract(year from e.hiredate)) = max(extract(year from e.hiredate))
```

Note that this query uses *standard* join syntax with the `on` keyword) rather than implicit join (with a comma in the `from` clause). This old syntax from decades ago should not be used in new code.

Also, all columns in the query should be qualified with the table they belong to, to avoid ambiguity; I made the assumption that `hiredate` belongs to table `emp`.